# Chat.SE bug (typo) on Android

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

When you aren't logged in, on the bottom of the screen there is a link that says "logged in" - this really confused me at first as I assumed, since I log into SE with Google, it automatically logged me in via my Google account (it is Android after all). Problem was... I couldn't figure out how to chat via my phone! I felt silly and even downloaded a different browser thinking maybe it was just a rendering problem since the menu button looks like its sitting on top of a text box.

I soon discovered this was a typo and that the "logged in" text was a link to the log in page so it should say "Log in" or something to that extent. (Once I logged in I could chat just fine)

Comment: I should probably add I only tested this on the GameDev.SE chat.

Comment: There's a whole sentence there -- "You must be logged in to chat." -- and the "logged in" part is a link. So in that context, the text is correct. The problem is that the non-link text is black-on-black in the gamedev room.

Comment: Ah! How about that!

Answer (score 3):

As I said in a comment, the actual text is in fact correct, since the link is part of the whole sentence "You must be **logged in** to chat." The issue was that the styling in the gamedev.se chat theme was incorrectly set up, so that the non-link text appeared in black-on-black. And that's of course as good as not being there at all.

That's fixed now. Thanks!